# Finding the wrong UIElement in Grid

Tags: wpf, .net-6.0

Problem: When I select a check box (in Column '1'), the `OnSelection` event should find a Label on Column '0' in the same Row, but I am getting:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.Label'.'

I am initializing the view as such:

```cs
Label lbName = new() { Content = "labelName" };
Grid.SetColumn(lbName, 0);
GrWindow.Children.Add(lbName);

CheckBox ckSelection = new();
ckSelection.Checked += OnSelection;
Grid.SetColumn(ckSelection, 1);
GrWindow.Children.Add(ckSelection);
```

And on the `OnSelection` method, where the exception is triggered:

```cs
string? labelName = GrWindow.Children.
                     Cast<Label>().
                     First(e => Grid.GetRow(e) == row && Grid.GetColumn(e) == 0).
                     Content as string;
```

In other place in my app, I am using a very similar approach to get a name from Row '0' and works fine.

There is only one children on every row/column = '0', and its a label, I dont know how to debug such situations, since the checkbox is on column='1'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
.Cast<Label>()
```

with

```
.OfType<Label>()
```

to get only the Labels.

Otherwise you are trying to cast all child elements to Label, which will of course fail for the CheckBox.

---

An alternative to querying the Children collection might be to assign the associated Label to the Tag property of the CheckBox

```
ckSelection.Tag = lblName;
```

and get it back in the event handler by

```
var checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
val label = (Label)checkBox.Tag;
```